# Getting webrick to work off of Windows Server 2008 on VMWare

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, virtual-machines, ruby-on-rails

I am setting up a separate external server (as a virtual machine) and decided to run Microsoft Outlook 2010 server on it as well as Webrick (temporary, will move to more robust server for production).

The performance for the exchange server is great however I am having trouble reaching the webrick server from outside the instance. The virtual machine is connected to the network in bridged mode and is assigned an IP which I can ping and access IIS 7 websites from. The virtual machine also has windows server 2008 R2 installed on it.

I am starting the Webrick server on port 3000 and I am even binding it to the static IP given to the instance however I believe that IIS or some other process is intercepting all http requests to the instance. With apache I could make a VirtualHost and handle it that way, is there anything similar for IIS? Or is the problem something completely different. Do I need to get rails working with IIS 7 via fcgi? i rather avoid this.

Since I am not using IIS for hosting websites can I just remove it? (I am not very experienced with windows server)

I realize this is a simple question and I would greatly appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check Windows Firewall.  It doesn't open port 3000 by default and may be the issue here.

IIS will only listen on the ports that you assign (with some extra listening on port 80).  So it won't take your port 3000 unless you've told it to.  You can uninstall it safely if you're not using it.

I bet it's Windows Firewall though.  You can also type 'netstat -abo' from the command line to find out what's listening on various ports.